# Android - Using the same keystore for debug and release

Tags: android

The recommendation in the docs is to use a different keystore for debug and release. I am wondering why is this recommended? What do we gain by having such different environments between Debug/Release?

I am not really sure that having two different APKs is a good idea. I want the debug environment to be as close as possible to the release.

Comment: I actually was looking for this so +1. The Google play services requires the same fingerprint for testing so I made my debug keystore the same as for release so I can just press a single button to test my app instead of releasing and manually installing it. But I wondered if this would be considered bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't need to give your release private key and password to every developer in your company so they can sign debug builds.

Comment: Interesting idea...but... the gradle build system maintains the username/password as part of the build scripts (FAIL). So IMHO the release keychain is not really hidden from developers.

Comment: You assume most of us use gradle.  Until the beta of Android Studio came out I'd never even heard of it.  And most still use Eclipse, going by the ratio of eclipse to AS questions here.